# how to delete last directory and its subfolders that created in a path using powershell

Tags: powershell

i want to delete a last directory of a path using powershell
this directory maybe have subfolders and i want to delete all of them.
e.g.
in drive "D:"   my last folder is "New Folder"
and "New Folder" have subdirectories e.g. "A" and "B" and "C"
i want to define paht of drive "D:" in powershell script and powerhshell check my last created directory that is "New Folder" and delete "New Folder" with all of that subdirectories.
i will be thank you that help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is readily broken into two steps:

1. Discover the newest directory
2. Remove it (and any items it contains)

We can discover the *newest* directory by enumerating *all directories* with `Get-ChildItem -Directory`, then sorting them based on their `CreationTime` property, and finally selecting only the newest:

```
$path = "D:\"

$newestDirectory = Get-ChildItem $path -Directory |Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |Select-Object -First 1
```

To remove the directory along with any contents without being prompted for confirmation, use `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force`:

```
$newestDirectory |Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it's exactly thing that i need.